# Is there a centralized library management for C? like rubygems for C?

Tags: c

So I was wondering if there is like a centralized library management for C? like [rubygems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) for C? I realized it might be a silly idea, but there are times when I wish I could have the benefits of rubygems, but for C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [package management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) have entries for C libraries.

Comment: Yea, but that changes from distro to distro, like lib names, and also there is a perhaps a version inflexibility... if C had its own centralized library management it would make it so much more cross platform compatible.